# Visited link property overrides current page item

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Im coding for quite a while but it seems i never got this problem before, or i just forget the tweak,  so anoying:)

I have a wordpress site set up, the menu links are a:(textual)

the css defined(part):

```
link (color:white;)
visited (color:white;)
hover (color:black;)
active (color:black)
```

now the problem is, i defined

current-menu-item

in wordpress, everything seams to change except the font color...
it seems "visited" is overriding the color...
how to fix this?

css:

```
#pages ul li { float: right; display: block; height: 37px; padding: 0px; }
        #pages ul li a:link { float: left; color: #FFF; display: block; height: 29px; font-size: 11px; padding: 7px 20px 0px 20px; margin: 0px; }

#pages ul li a:visited {float: left; color:#fff; display: block; height: 29px; font-size: 11px; padding: 7px 20px 0px 20px; margin: 0px;}

#pages ul li a:hover { background-position: top; background-repeat: no-repeat; margin: 0px; color: black;}
#pages ul li a:active {background-position: top; background-repeat: no-repeat; margin: 0px; color: black;}
.current-menu-item a:link, .current-post-ancestor a:link, .current-menu-parent a:link, .current-post-parent a:link {background-position: top; background-repeat: no-repeat; margin: 0px; color:black; }
```

Comment: Can you show us your real CSS? You seem to have left out large chunks of your selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css hierarchy

your selectors are only 2 levels deep .current-menu-item a:link, .current-post-ancestor a:link, .current-menu-parent a:link, .current-post-parent a:link

wordpress selectors are 4 levels deep #pages ul li a:visited, and also it has an ID which makes it weight more than your css rule.

try adding an id and selectors on your css rule to be read by the browser and overwrite WP's css rule.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your menu css is loaded after the css file that sets the styles for link, visited, hover etc.

Or if the previous is not possible make the current-menu-item style's color property !important:

```
.current-menu-item {
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `!important`, it is a sledgehammer that only works once.

Comment: I totally agree with that :) Though sometimes a guy just needs a quick patch because a pissed off client wont allow the time needed to do it right :)